# How to get a button to open a web page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've looked everywhere, including the MSDN forums, but no one has even mentioned this or ways to do it. The basic idea is that once a Button is dragged from the toolkit, how do you then link that button to a web page, ie I have a 'Facebook' button, how do I then make it so that when the button is clicked, Facebook opens in a new browser window?

Comment: Web or Win app? Might want to add a tag for it.

Answer (score 20):

Once you've dragged the button onto the designer, you can double-click on it to open up the Button's `Click` event handler.  This is the code that will get run when the user clicks.  You can then add the required logic, ie:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Launch browser to facebook...
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.facebook.com");
}
```

Comment: How can you send information to the website you are opening? Say that the landing page has a search bar and you want to send a keyword to be looked up.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Process.Start with the desired URL to open the default browser and navigate to the page:

```
using system.Diagnostics;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("http://www.YouTube.com");
}
```

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified." System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Answer (score 0):

Since you said open in a **new** browser window, I was thinking the context was an web application you were developing, so this would apply in that case:

Add an HTML button with the `window.open` JavaScript method.  You don't need or want code-behind here because it's all happening on the client. Here's a snippet, and there are a few other options you can pass to `window.open` to control behavior.

```
        <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Facebook" onclick="window.open('http://facebook.com')"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Process class` under `System.dll` which is be default added to the solution. But you should refer the namespace at the top of your class this way:

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public class MyProgram
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.facebook.com");
        }
    }
}
```